# Using a FILTER function in conjunction with other functions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fz9PdnyOrQOgm4AdWXP8jgyg9uEgzwMu6u-Q7_9WxSs/edit#gid=0)

I am looking for a function to display the Title (from column B) that has the lowest numerical average in column (found from column G). I have that already in the form of

`=INDEX(B2:G,match(min(G2:G),G2:G,FALSE),1)`

but I would like to further specify it so that it only grabs the Title with the lowest average, that is also of a certain Category. So let's say I'd want a function to search for the Title with the lowest average only in Category A, I would want that to display "B" instead of "K", which the above function outputs.

Answer (score 0):

- **CAT A: `=INDEX(B2:G5;   MATCH(MIN(G2:G5);   G2:G5;   0); 1)`**
- **CAT B: `=INDEX(B6:G11;  MATCH(MIN(G6:G11);  G6:G11;  0); 1)`**
- **CAT C: `=INDEX(B12:G15; MATCH(MIN(G12:G15); G12:G15; 0); 1)`**

[image]

**[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fz9PdnyOrQOgm4AdWXP8jgyg9uEgzwMu6u-Q7_9WxSs/edit#gid=1586162566)**

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to make it search for the category? So if I have multiple instances of Category A in the I column, I won't have to add the ranges manually?

Comment: @Arynthesizer you would need to unmerge cells under Category for that

Answer (score 0):

Do unmerge I2:I. And fill all corresponding rows with category name to use FILTER.

Answer (score 0):

- **CAT A: `=INDEX(B2:B; MATCH(MIN(FILTER(G2:G; I2:I = "Category A")); G2:G; 0))`**
- **CAT B: `=INDEX(B2:B; MATCH(MIN(FILTER(G2:G; I2:I = "Category B")); G2:G; 0))`**
- **CAT C: `=INDEX(B2:B; MATCH(MIN(FILTER(G2:G; I2:I = "Category C")); G2:G; 0))`**

[image]

**[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fz9PdnyOrQOgm4AdWXP8jgyg9uEgzwMu6u-Q7_9WxSs/edit#gid=1606687734)**